# How create list of descendant nodes

Tags: nodes

How can I create page with Drupal 7 - views 3 module where are descendant nodes of the parent node.
The structure of nodes is following:

Parent node

-Descendant 1

--Descendant 2

-Descendant 3

--Descendant 4

---Descendant 5

etd.

I would like to list all of these descendants.
Im trying it with book module, but without success.